# How to show Native Google Maps inside a Modal?

Tags: google-maps, ionic3

I am trying to show the ionic native google maps in my Ionic 3 application. I have a tab project. So, i want to open the google map in a modal and get some data back to the calling page. But, the transparent windows is showing.  I saw another issue [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-google-maps-not-working-inside-a-modal/89171) and followed the solution give there like below in **app.scss**:

```
ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ .nav-decor{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

But, it did not fix my problem. Still can't see the google map in the modal.

Then tried to follow another [solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-google-maps-not-working-inside-a-modal/89171/8?u=setu1421) but still can't manage to appear the google map in the modal.

In **home.ts**:

```
 openMap() {
    this.isModal = true;
    let mapModal = this.modalCtrl.create('MapFilterPage');
    mapModal.onDidDismiss((data) => {
      this.isModal = false;
    });
    mapModal.present();
  }
```

In **home.html**:

```
<ion-content [style.opacity]="isModal ? 0 : 1" padding>
      <button ion-button item-right >
        <ion-icon name="add" (click)="openMap()"></ion-icon>
      </button>
</ion-content>
```

But, when tried to use below code, the google maps is showing fine.

`this.navCtrl.setRoot('MapFilterPage');`

How to show google maps in modal properly?

Comment: Did you import `ModalController` properly? Does the page appear blank or it doesn't even load?